# If $X$ and $Y$ are Normally distributed with correlation $\rho$, can we say anything about $E[Y \mid X]?$

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, correlation

Let $X \sim N(0, 1)$ and $Y \sim N(0, 1)$ and $\mathbb E[XY]=\rho$. Can one say anything about the conditional expectation $\mathbb E[X \mid Y]$?

In general, this clearly does not seem to work, because $\mathbb E[X \mid Y]$ will depend on the joint distribution of $X, Y$ while $\rho$ only measure linear relationship between them. But is it possible to say anything in the Normal case?

It is mentioned in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent) that if $X, Y$ have a jointly Normal distribution then $\rho=0$ implies independence, i.e. we know $E[X \mid Y] = E[X]$. But is this as far as one can go in terms of inferences about $E[X \mid Y]$ from the correlation?

Comment: A proof of the result, which is given in the answer of leonbloy can be seen here (page 3): http://athenasc.com/Bivariate-Normal.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are told that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Normal, then we [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) that

$$E[X|Y] = E[X] + \rho \frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}( Y-E[Y])$$

which in your case reduces to $$E[X|Y] =  \rho Y$$

In general, if we only know that the variables are marginally normal, then I don't think there's much to say. Calling $E[X|Y]=g(Y)$
we know that $$E[XY] = E[E[XY|Y]] =E[Y g(Y)] )= \int y \, g(y) \exp{(-y^2/2}) \,dy =\rho $$  and $$E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]=E[g(Y)]=\int  g(y) \exp{(-y^2/2}) \,dy=0$$
but this does not say much.

Comment: Could you provide the proof for the statement please?

Comment: We actually know $X|Y$ is normal with mean $pY$ and variance $1-p^2$.  This is the second time today where you can use the "Conditional Distributions of Multivariate Normal Distributions" (Wikipedia has the relevant section in their "Multivariate normal distribution" page), which will have the technique need to prove leonbloy's statement,  but that's probably overkill. 

I can't find a friendly proof that gives the distribution of $X|Y$ without resorting to the theory of random vectors, but there has to be one out there that only deals with two random normal variables.

Comment: @Exatic See eg https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/118 or http://athenasc.com/Bivariate-Normal.pdf